Why do guitars have different position markers than almost all other fretted instruments?
If you look at banjos, mandolins, ukuleles, and balalaikas, almost all of them have a position marker at the 10th fret whereas almost all guitars mark the 9th fret instead. What accounts for the difference?

Never noticed that before. Good question!

Most guitars I've seen mark the 5th, 7th and 12th and that's it. Only a minority add the 3rd, 9th, 15th... Though that doesn't answer your question how it came to be that it's 9th and not 10th.

@Divizna - 3,5,7,9 and 12 on quite a few.  And basses follow suit. Doubled up from 12 to 24 with the same pattern. I even have guitars with a 1st fret marker - maybe for the very thick players...

Does this answer your question? Position of white dots in guitar fretboard

I found an interesting duplicate where a few of the answers reference the harmonic series. I don’t know if there is a documented reason for this but I think it is a combination of usefulness, symmetry, and the fact that those frets are important reference points.

Not a duplicate! That doesn't answer the question. I get why you would choose 5, 7, 9, 12, 15, 17, 19, and 21. Why the difference on all other fretted instruments? It can't just be the harmonic series. The harmonic series is the same on all stringed instruments.

My first thought was to the banjo and the blues scale, but that wouldn't explain the mandolin or the balalaika.

@Divizna I think you’re seeing mostly classical guitars. Steel string acoustics and electrics always have a dot at 9 and often at 3.

Mandolins are violin tuned, not guitar tuned. The frets you want to find are different

@david Well, and ukuleles and banjos are often reentrant. But the harmonics are always the same. (Maybe it's about how harmonics became more important to guitar?) I'd be very interested in the historical aspect of this question. I don't have time to do the deep dive into iconography, but representations of baroque-era guitars show elaborate fretboard ornamentation, but not seemingly in ways that mark particular frets. And vihuelas seem to be often plainer and totally unmarked.

If you figure there is a reason, I would expect it to be a harmonic reason. And of the various harmonic reasons you could be concerned with, I would expect things like tonal degrees, major triad tones, and tonic/dominant relationships are the important concerns.
The 12th fret marker is obvious, it provides the octave point for each string.
The 5th and 7th frets also seem obvious, they mark a P4 and P5 on each string, tonal degrees relative to the string.
When strings are tuned by P5 then the higher string of a pair fretted at the 10th fret will form a minor seventh above the higher string, which could be understood as part of a dominant seventh chord. Ex. string pair G D, D string at the 10th fret is C, the seventh of G:V7.
When strings are tunes by P4 then the lower string of a pair fretted at the 9th fret forms a M6 above the lower string, but is also a M3 above the higher string. Taken together you have the tones of a major triad rooted on the higher string. Ex. strings E A, A string at the 9th fret is C#, E C# A are the tones of an A major triad rooted on the A string.
I don't know if there is a definitive answer to this question. I would expect historic examples could be found of various instruments with markers at positions differing from what is common today. But if you want some sensible way to understand their positions, you can look at the harmonic relationship to adjacent strings.
FWIW, the 3rd fret on guitar, on the low and high E strings, marks G, which makes sense, because standard tuning is roughly designed around G major.
